# generate form with workflow

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-server

I am using SharePoint server 2013 with an Enterprise wiki template.

Now I am trying to create a page that contains a form where users can fill in what type of sandwich they want to eat at noon. At around 11AM the results should be mailed to a certain adress. Users who have filled the form in have to recognized by AD and send with their choises. Users do not have to fill in there names.

The mail will be something like this  :

User : Mark Levan
Choise : Sandwich ham and cheese.

Is this possible?

Thanks !

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

Is it ok if results are mailed not around 11AM, but immediately after creating WF?

**If so then you can do as follows**:

1. Create list "Sandwich requests" with necessary fields (for instance, sandwich types lookups).
2. After that you can create a List WF on this list, which would have only one activity (send email). In the body of the email you can use "CurrentItem:CreatedBy" to refer to a user which created item.
3. And the last step you have to make this workflow to start automatically on item adding.

**So, after that your solution will work as follows:**

1. User creates new Sandwich request by creating new item in "Sandwich requests". He fills in all the necessary fields and save the request.
2. Workflow starts automatically right after item is saved.
3. Workflow sends email to a certain address. In the body of the email it has username and its order.

Could this solution work for you?

If some points should be described in more details, just let me know.

PS: If you need to send it in exact time (11AM), you can use [Pause until Date action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164026.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your requirements by creating a custom SharePoint timer job scheduled to run everyday at 11am. You setup a custom list and get users to create items any time. Your code will iterate through the list items and send e-mails to each recipient using the SPUtility.SendEMail method. No workflow is required!

Reference:

[Sample code custom timer job](http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/)

[Custom timer job more detailed](http://dotnetfinder.wordpress.com/2010/07/24/creatingcustomsharepointtimerjob2010/)

Nice blog [post](http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2008/05/using-the-undocumented-sputilitysendemail-method/) for SPUtility.SendEmail